# Storing CLLocationCoordinates in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, mapkit, cllocation, mkmapitem

I've encountered an issue when storing a `MKMapItem` that I was able to resolve by looking at compiler warnings, but I don't understand *why* I was able to resolve it or if I utilized "best practices".

I have an Object model that stores latitude and longitude coordinates from an `MKMapItem` separately as `double`s in an `NSManagedObject`. When I go to `Editor\Create NSManagedObject Subclass` and create the my class, the header looks like this:

```
@class LocationCategory;

@interface PointOfInterest : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
// Xcode spat out NSNumber instead of the double specified in the model setup screen
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * note;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LocationCategory *locationCategory;

@end
```

All was well until I tried to add an object to my `managedObjectContext` I got these warnings:

```
Assigning to 'NSNumber *' from incompatible type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double')
```

on these lines:

```
newPOI.latitude = self.item.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
newPOI.longitude = self.item.placemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

**I fixed it by changing my `PointOfInterest : NSManagedObject` subclass:**

```
@property (nonatomic) double latitude;
@property (nonatomic) double longitude;
```

Is this the best way to make the compiler happy or is there a better way?

Comment: Your solution is entirely reasonable and valid. Really, there's no need to change it or to worry that you're doing anything wrong, it's a good solution as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you change the properties of your PointOfInterest subclass back to NSNumber, and then change your assignment of latitude and longitude as follows:

```
newPOI.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.item.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude];
newPOI.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.item.placemark.location.coordinate.longitude];
```

Then when you want to use the latitude:

```
self.item.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude = [newPOI.latitude doubleValue];
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! My "solution" felt a little forced/hackish. I'm glad I posted a question because I learned something. Thanks again.

Comment: @AdrianB Glad I could help.  Have fun with your project!

Comment: @Steve , can you clarify why you're suggesting to *not* use scalars? Scalars have been supported on managed object subclasses for quite some time. The author's "solution" used scalars and was entirely correct.

Comment: @quellish In the event that a location is not available, NSNumber will allow a nil setting -- 0 latitude and 0 longitude are a valid latitude/longitude pair and shouldn't be used to indicate that a location was not specified, whereas nil would indicate that the data has not been set.